# Is it possible to store to ISODate field w/o using ISODate()?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We are trying to use MongoDB with a Layer 7 SecureSpan Gateway (SSG).  Layer 7 has provided us with a piece of software called a custom assertion, the provides a kind of bridge between the SSG and MongoDB.  With this, it allows us to configure that with a query string and then we can invoke it and it performs the query.

We also want to use the MongoDB TTL indexes feature, so we want to store a field for each document/row, CREATED_FOR_TTL, that would contain a date/timestamp and that would be configured as a TTL index.

The SSG has these things called "context variables" or CVs, and the MongoDB assertion allows using a CV as the query string, i.e., we can construct a query string in a CV, and then invoke the custom assertion using the constructed CV.

However, we are encountering a problem, because, while the SSG does allow a CV to be used for the query string, it doesn't allow a CV to be used with MongoDB functions, and in particular, the following doesn't work in a query string:

CREATED_FOR_TTL : INFODate()

The SSG does have functions that would allow us take a date/timestamp and and convert it to a millisecond value.

However, when we do:

CREATED_FOR_TTL: , e.g.:

CREATED_FOR_TTL: 1234567890...

What we end up with in MongoDB is a NumberLong(xxxxxx) and that doesn't seem to work with the TTL index functionality.

So, per the Subject, I'm trying to find out if there anyway we can take (for example) a CV that contains an integer (i.e., the date/timestamp in millisecs) and store that into the 
field such that it would, to MongDB and to the TTL indexing, look like an ISODate()?

My apologies for the longish question, but I realize that this is probably a kind of odd question, plus I wanted to provide the background of why we were looking for this.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: TTL Indexes require the indexed field to be a date type. You could write your own process, but really this seems to be an epoch timestamp anyway. Why not just convert the type to a date when you insert the data? Forgive me if you said so, but TLDR. Better if you get to the point.

Answer (score 0):

The actual server process mongod doesn't know what `ISODate()` is. `ISODate()` is a helper in the mongo shell. MongoDB stores BSON and the TTL index field must be of the [BSON date type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date). You don't submit query strings to mongod, you send wire protocol messages that include the query document as BSON. So the real question is, how are you encoding your queries and sending BSON to MongoDB? Normally, people use drivers that handle all this but it seems like you are using something else, something I'm totally unfamiliar with. If it doesn't support the full wire protocol/encoding all the BSON types MongoDB needs to support your use cases, then you need to fix that communication layer between you and MongoDB.